# Stacked Icons on Bootstrap Button

Tags: gwt, twitter-bootstrap-3

is there a way to have stacked icons on a bootstrap3 button? I use gwtbootstrap3 which uses bootstrap 3.3.6.

Thanks in advance
Hannes

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way but it works:

```
<b:PanelBody ui:field="test">
  <b:Button ui:field="buttonTest">
    s
  </b:Button>
  <b:Image type="THUMBNAIL" url="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/drf/PNG/color.png" ui:field="img1"/>
  <b:Image type="THUMBNAIL" url="http://codeissue.com/images/check_icon_small.png" ui:field="img2"/>
</b:PanelBody>
```

in run time:

```
decleration:
  @UiField Button buttonTest;
  @UiField Image img1;
  @UiField Image img2;
  @UiField PanelBody test;

In the constructor:
  test.setStyleName("fa-stack fa-lg");
  img1.setStyleName("fa fa-stack-2x");
  buttonTest.setStyleName("fa fa-stack-2x");
  img2.setStyleName("fa fa-stack-1x");
```

the result:
[image: result]